# C++ LogonUser() API is slow when authenticating accounts with bad domains

Tags: c++, winapi, authentication, dns

I'm using the following code:

```
HANDLE token;
if (!LogonUser("LocalUser", "InvalidDomain", "Password", LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token))
{
    unsigned long error = GetLastError();
}
```

When the machine is on a domain, and an invalid domain is entered, it can take a really long time to authenticate the login.  This can range from 5 seconds to 2/3 minutes.

Is there a way to improve on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old issue, I had the same problem years ago. As a workaround, you can use WaitForSingleObject. The basic idea is to start a thread that will execute the LogonUser and make the main thread wait n miliseconds for a handle that the worker thread will set when it is done.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE athEvent;
DWORD WINAPI ThreadAuth(LPVOID);
DWORD AUTHTIMEOUT = 5000;

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD dwEvent, dwThreadID;

    athEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadAuth, NULL,
        0, &dwThreadID); 

    // Wait for the thread to signal
    dwEvent = WaitForSingleObject(athEvent, AUTHTIMEOUT); //5 seconds timeout

    switch (dwEvent)
    {
        // athEvent was signaled
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            printf("Authenticated");
            break;
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            printf("Authenticate timeout\n");
            TerminateThread(hThread, 0);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wait error: %d\n", GetLastError());
            ExitProcess(0);
    }

    CloseHandle(athEvent);
    CloseHandle(hThread);

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadAuth(LPVOID lpParam)
{

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpParam);

    //## Insert your logon method here
    //LogonUser("LocalUser", "InvalidDomain", "Password", LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token)
    Sleep(5000); //if >= AUTHTIMEOUT then the waitforsingleobject will expire
    //##

    //Signal the event so WaitForSingleObject is released
    SetEvent(athEvent);

    return 0;
}
```